# How does the sort in Quotelineitems work?

Tags: visualforce, quotelineitem

How does Sort button work on Quotelineitems?
I am trying to get the same way of sorting on VF page. I am opening a VF page to add and edit lineitems. i want the VF page to show the same sorting which the user has set up using the sort.

**EDIT :**

I was really wanting to see what the logic was for it. Is it based on the line number or some other field which it sets internally and accordingly displays it. If someone sets it up using the sort button i need to have it come in my VF page also in the same order.

Any insights would be of great help

Comment: You can't exactly replicate it, as it's a built-in feature. You could write your own, though.

Comment: I was really wanting to see what the logic was for it was. Is it based on the line number or some other field which it sets internally and accordingly displays it. If someone sets it up using the sort button i need to have it come in my VF page also in the same order.

Comment: It's a field called SortOrder. You should be able to query the field and sort by it.

Comment: Thanks that worked. if you can add it as an answer i can accept the answer